# Drop down menu problems and positioning

Tags: html, css

I've used a template for a drop down menu online and tried modifying the code as much as possible however i'm totally stumped on what to do next. I'm trying to get the menu to center on the page with a 70% width, so this will align to the images and text, however no matter what i try to change this doesn't work. I've had a look around and it is mentioned a few times that relative positioning can mess around with

Also in the drop down menu, i'm trying to get away with having to use em and get onto using percentages but whenever i try to change indexmenu a's width to percentages, it totally ruins everything. Sorry if this isn't the best worded question i'm just trying to give as much information as possible (Ignore the colours and crappy images it's for layout only)

[Website link](http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w10035738/Stages/slideshow.html)

Thanks in advance!

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
        <link href="slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Stages School Of Dance</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="indexmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="General.html">General Classes</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="venue.html">Venue</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery And Video </a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">2007</a>

                            <div class="nav2">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">January</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">February</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">2008</a>

                            <div class="nav2">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">March</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">May</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">2009</a>

                            <div class="nav2">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">June</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">July</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">2010</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">2011</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="studentlife.html">Student Life</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="index1">
            <div id="slideshowContainer">
                <div class="slideshow">
                    <img src="4.jpg" />
                    <img src="2.jpg" />
                    <img src="1.jpg" />
                    <img src="3.jpg" />
                    <img src="5.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="indexaboutus">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit condimentum mi id sodales. Mauris eu nisl nec nibh aliquam cursus ut quis lacus. Duis et erat non sem sollicitudin volutpat a eget lorem. Integer feugiat diam vitae odio auctor gravida. Nullam congue nisi nec felis tristique, id fringilla quam ullamcorper. Cras a sem at justo imperdiet sagittis sodales id eros. Cras tristique urna ipsum, vel sagittis tortor imperdiet ac. Duis volutpat lacus sem, et molestie risus dapibus vitae. Mauris convallis elit sed sapien consectetur fringilla. Nulla consectetur mollis libero, vel eleifend purus rutrum ut. Donec posuere velit leo, et facilisis est vehicula non. Aliquam vel turpis felis. Sed molestie orci sem, in lobortis dui tempor eu. Morbi tempor mauris et aliquam consequat.</p>
                <p>Cras id sodales tellus, ut euismod erat. Nunc mi lacus, lobortis nec metus in, laoreet vehicula enim. Fusce semper velit et augue viverra vulputate. Donec suscipit lorem sed nulla tincidunt sodales. Nullam vehicula arcu sapien, sit amet posuere augue tristique pellentesque. Integer sit amet pretium leo, non lobortis dolor. Vivamus sodales eget leo in rhoncus. Phasellus quis dolor faucibus, convallis metus eget, sodales diam. Nulla scelerisque, magna eget placerat gravida, neque ante fringilla enim, at aliquet tortor nibh accumsan quam. Pellentesque iaculis elementum dolor, sed facilisis felis scelerisque sit amet. Praesent aliquam diam erat, eu pellentesque magna blandit ut. Donec vulputate luctus tellus, at iaculis felis faucibus sit amet. Nam nec diam elit. Integer cursus varius ante, nec ullamcorper risus tristique eu. Fusce sed posuere sem.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <img id="logo1" src="logo2.jpg" alt="Slideshow" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

### CSS

```
body {

    background-color:green;
}

#index1 {
    padding-top:2%;
    width:70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#indexmenu {
    clear:both;
    border-style:solid;
    margin-left:20%;
}

#indexaboutus {
    width:45%;
    float:right;

}


#slideshowContainer {
    float:left;
    width:35%;

}


.slideshow {
    height: 50%;
}
.slideshow img {
}



#indexmenu {   /*  */
    width:80%;
    position:relative;
    left:13%;
}

.nav2 {   /*  */
    margin-left:-50%;

}


#indexmenu, #indexmenu ul {   /*  */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#indexmenu a {    /* changes menu width MUST CHANGE */
    display: block;
        width:10em;
}


#indexmenu ul li a {


}

#indexmenu li {    /* Xhanged all menu text */
    float: left;
        font-size:115%;
}


.nav2 li {    /*Sets year and month  */


}

#indexmenu li ul {    /*Changes year and month text  */
    position: absolute;
    width: 6%;
        font-size:80%;
    left: -999em;
}

#indexmenu li:hover ul {  /*  */
    left: auto;
}


#indexmenu li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul {  /*  */
    left: auto;
}

#indexmenu li ul li {
        margin-left:-50%;
        margin-top:-5%;

}
#indexmenu li ul ul {                 /*  A, B, C, D - A sets the X axis, D sets the Y axis of the months */
    margin: -42% 0 0 180%;

}

#indexmenu li a {                     /*sets all of the links in the id nav, in li and a  */
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;

}



#indexmenu, #indexmenu ul {              /*  */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none; 
    line-height: 1;
}



#indexmenu li:hover ul ul, #indexmenu li.sfhover ul ul {   /*  */
    left: -999em;
}



#indexmenu li:hover ul, #indexmenu li li:hover ul, #indexmenu li.sfhover ul, #indexmenu li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}


#indexmenu li ul li a {      /* sets the  month and year in drop down option*/
        font-size:100%;
        margin-top:15%;
}


.logo   {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        margin-left:15%;
    width:70%;
        padding-top:2%;
}


#logo1 {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only specify a `width`, and then use `margin:0 auto;` also make sure that this is applied to the `<div>`. Take off the `position:relative` and anything else.

Also make sure you set `text-align:center` in the `<div>` as well to get the `<li>` text positioned in the centre.

```
div { margin:0px auto; max-width: 80%; min-width:70%; width: 80%; }
ul { list-style-type:none; }
ul li { display: inline-block; padding:4px 7px; }
ul li a { text-decoration:none; color: black; }
```

This is usually what I use to start my menus off. I use `max-width` as it seems to constrain the `width` when `width` doesn't.

If you use a reset css file (search google for reset css) you don't need to set any other property such as `<a>` `width` because it will take be the width of its parent. Same with every other element, if you want it to be the `width` of its content use the `float:left` or `float:right` but make sure you put in the a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` in after it so that parent container becomes the `height` of its children. If you don't you will notice that the parent will have no `height`.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMRQV/) to help you play around and figure it out.

You need to observe the Box Model in `HTML`, look at here [Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) and remember that `margin` `padding` `border` `outline` will add to your elements `width`, so make sure you take this into account when you specify a `width`, because the overall `width` will be including the box model.

Comment: Where exactly should I only specify margin:0 auto; and which part of the ul? Sorry about the silly questions just this has my brain scrambled


Edit..
Thanks alot ill have a bash at this now!

Comment: Please see my new Edit @Xiah , its got a new fiddle, you need to try and align your page to use these symantics, use www.w3schools.com to help you out with creating webpages.

Comment: @Xiah if this answer has helped you out, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: I tried your way but just couldn't get my head around it :( i've tried another method and got to the below jsfiddle, i've got the menu working fine and the drop down menu works almost as I want, but the drop down option is re-arranging my original menu. I've tried everything I can think of to get it to work and tried google, but I can't find exactly what i'm looking for. This is the fiddle i'm using jsfiddle.net/xiah01/7WLkZ/248

Comment: Its moving it down because you're changing the height and width of the ul, you must go onto w3schools and learn how to form proper html markup and how to apply correct css styles otherwise you'll just be stabbing around in the dark.

Comment: @Xiah your html markup is incorrect as well, you can't have a `<ul>` with nested `<div>` tags you must only nest `<li>` tags with in

Comment: @Xiah here is a working example of what you're trying to achieve [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WLkZ/249/)

Comment: I was just stabbing in the dark and somehow managed to get it working, with this working i'll be able to understand what i'm doing! Massive help thanks alot :)

Comment: @Xiah I'm glad to have helped, please take onboard all advice to get the most out of HTML and CSS